# How to make Qt widgets resizeable?

Tags: qt, python-2.7, widget, qtableview

I want to create an application which consists of a `QLineEdit` and two `QTableView` widgets in vertical layout.

*Sample code:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>401</width>
     <height>301</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView_2"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>lineEdit</sender>
   <signal>returnPressed()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>close()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>200</x>
     <y>14</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>199</x>
     <y>149</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

But these `QTableView` widgets are not resizable. I didn't found any property in `Qt` for this.

So how can I make these `QTableView` widgets resizable or auto expand and contract?

means if I reduce size of first `QTableView` widget then automatically size of second `QTableView` widget should increase means every widget should expand or contract automatically if I change size of any widget inside Vertical Layout at run time.

The sample code was designed in `Qt4 Designer` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Comment: @Chernobyl I want resize widget by mouse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break the current layout, select the two widgets, click `Layout Vertically in Splitter` and finally select the form and click the `layout vertically`.
[image]

Comment: Layout vertically in splitter ?

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, but I don't know python. Anyways Zlatomir's solution is good too. +1 for him.

Comment: @Zlatomir Done as said but in preview at borders of QTableView widget is not showing any symbol of resizing it.

Comment: @Zlatomir I want something similar to sizeGripEnabled property of QDialog for widgets.

Comment: In that case i think you'll need to inherit from QSplitter and draw the handle the way you want it to, or use stylesheets to customize the splitter (it looks that you can put an image in there): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qsplitter

Comment: I never used this, but i looked now and it seems you can set the stylesheet in the designer: select the splitter and at the properties search the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't have a layout on your `QDialog`. What you did was you dragged a vertical layout on top of the dialog, now the dialog contains the layout which is `absolute` positioned and is not linked to the dialog. What you want to do is move the all the widgets from the vertical layout on top of a `QSplitter`, right click on the `QDialog` and at the `Lay out` context menu entry choose `Lay Out Vertically`, or alternatively click the `QDialog` and press `Ctrl + 2`. The result should be the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>405</width>
    <height>305</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
     <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView_2"/>
     <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView"/>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

What I recommend is reading the [Qt Layout Management Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html) for more info on this topic.

Comment: @luliu I tried your code and it also don't give option of resizing widgets when mouse is placed over their borders.

Comment: @Patrick so you want to change the height of each widget by dragging the zone between the widgets?

Comment: @luilu yES your code worked. But in a new file I am not able to select splitter in QT.